# How to have multiple columns in a row of UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to generate multiple columns in cells and center align my cells. I want a maximum width of cells and in case my maximum width is reached i want cells to increase in height only. But incase the maximum width is not reached I want to show more columns in that cells. The image for which I am trying is attached.[image]

Comment: Use flow layout

Comment: can you give me an example

Comment: You might need to use your own custom UICollectionViewLayout and work it all out yourself unfortunately.

Comment: Just Google it.